# Get help on errors in TeXnicCenter

Tags: errors, compiling, texniccenter

Sometimes, I get errors when I compile with pdfLaTeX in TeXnicCenter. Looking through the error logs, I get something like:

```
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

How do I take advantage of this `Type H <return> for immediate help`? I'm new to LaTeX and I would purposefully introduce errors to my source so I could learn more about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your plan is to "purposefully introduce errors to my source so I could learn more about them", you might find this will help expedite your cunningly twisted goals:

Define a new profile in `TeXnicCenter`:

1. Choose `Define Output Profiles...` from `TeXnicCenter`'s `Build` menu
2. Select the profile you'd like to use, e.g., `LaTeX => PDF`
3. Clone it by clicking the `Copy` button
4. Give it a nice new name, e.g., `LaTeX => PDF (shell)`
5. In the `Path to the (La)TeX compiler` box, type `launchpdflatex.bat`
6. In the `Command line arguments to pass to the compiler` box, type `"%pm"`

Create a new file called `launchpdflatex.bat` containing this line:

```
start cmd /K pdflatex.exe -interaction=errorstopmode %1
```

(you can omit the `-interaction=errorstopmode` part if you like.)

Save this file somewhere in your system path.  (NB, this command assumes that the shell processor can also find `pdflatex.exe` somewhere in your system path.)

Now, whenever you've run a compile that has errors in it for which you'd like to `Type H <return>`, simply select your `LaTeX => PDF (shell)` profile from `TeXnicCenter`'s `LaTeX` toolbar dropdown listbox and, voila, it will launch `pdflatex` in an interactive command shell for you. (Of course, `TeXnicCenter` won't run `makeindex` or whatever other postprocessor commands you have in your build profile, but, hey, you've got an error to deal with, so there's no point in chugging any further along.)

Answer (score 2):

Texniccenter builds the file in a way similar to a silent mode, and displays you only a subset of the log file.
You can take advantage of the live help (`type H for help`) only if you build the file from a command prompt. That is: open a command prompt, go to the folder of the files you are working on, issue the command `pdflatex filename.tex` and see the output.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with TeXnicCenter, but why not just run pdflatex on the file and then type H when you get an error?

Comment: I'd answer your question like this: Because one of the advantages of TeXnicCenter is that you can compile out of the interface either by clicking a button or by using a key combination. With its "compile and view" function you can go directly from the editor to the viewer.

Comment: @doncherry: I fail to see how that addresses my suggestion. Alessandro's suggestion is identical to mine, I note.

Comment: It is, but you were asking a question that didn't seem purely rhetorical to me. So, to clarify: What you're suggesting (as well as Alessandro) is giving up something that users of TC perceive as an advantage of TC. If you use TC you _don't have_ to go to command prompt and type in `pdflatex file.tex`, you can use the editor's functionality for this. Obviously, the downside of this is that you can't really influence the compiling once it has started. Hope this helps?

Comment: @doncherry: I was suggesting that to solve this particular issue: namely being able to issue the H to TeX, it would be possible to simply run pdflatex on the file. I'm not sure why you think I'm suggesting giving up using TC.